# how can i display selected items on the dropdowncheckboxes caption box in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my web application, i need to display all the selected items on the caption box in my dropdowncheckboxes like this

[image]

for example the above image selected 3 or 4 items but it shows only 2 items. the remaining items are not visible. whatever i selected items i need to see all items on the caption box.

.Aspx:

```
    <%@ Register Namespace="Saplin.Controls" Assembly="DropDownCheckBoxes" TagPrefix="asp"%>
 <asp:DropDownCheckBoxes ID="dropdown1" runat="server" UseSelectAllNode="true"  UseButtons="true"  
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
            <Style DropDownBoxBoxWidth="200"/> </asp:DropDownCheckBoxes>
```

.CS:

```
protected void dropdown1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 List<String> checkedList = new List<string>();
 foreach (ListItem item in dropdown1.Items) 
{ 
if (item.Selected)
 {    
    checkedList.Add(item.Text);
 }
 }    
dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption = String.Join(",", checkedList);
}
```

Can anyone help me how to do this.

Thank you

Comment: show us the code for the dropdown

Comment: Hi katz, i updated my code can you see once.Thank you

Comment: Hi, me also searching for same thing can anyone help me out.

Comment: as moustafaS wrote you need to adjust the width of the dropdown

Comment: if i adjust this width in case i will get large names on every item i need to adjust width. It's working for small item names only

Comment: Hi, can anyone tell me how to do this

Answer (score -1):

You need to adjust the width of the dropdown to accommodate for many options selected, try setting width to 250px and then selecting.

Comment: hi,thank you for your respond. If in case i have large item names in my dropdown i need to adjust width until items are properly displaying is it correct to increase width in all the times. Thank you

Comment: when i complied my code at that time selected items are displaying at "dropdown1.Texts.SelectBoxCaption" and when i see the result at last it will not display properly. can anyone tell me how to do this